# Wrap echo into a textarea using PHP

Tags: php

Can someone maybe tell me why this is not working?

I have used echo to build a form around the results:

```
echo "[$key:]$value";
    echo "[$key:]<br>";
```

to try to capture it into a textarea so that I can submit the result to a new page, when I do this the page shows blank....

```
<?php

/**
 * Function to read meta information from the given domain.
 *
 * @param string $domain
 */

  // Read META info
  $tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.cheap-flight.co.za');

  // Check the result and display it.
  if (sizeof($tags) == 0){
    echo '<div>No META information was found!</div>';
  }
    echo '<form name="form1" method="post" action="">'
    echo '<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5">'
  foreach ($tags as $key=>$value) {
    echo "[$key:]$value";
    echo "[$key:]<br>";
  }
  echo '</textarea></form>'

?>
```

The ideal would be to have it like this:

```
echo "<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5">[$key:]$value</textarea>";
```

and place each result into it's own textarea...

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If that's pulled straight from your code you're missing a lot of semicolons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `;` at the end of your lines. And I would put the loop in an `else` statement, otherwise it does not make sense.

```
if (sizeof($tags) == 0){
    echo '<div>No META information was found!</div>';
}
else {
    echo '<form name="form1" method="post" action="">';
    echo '<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5">';
    foreach ($tags as $key=>$value) {
        echo "[$key:]$value";
    }
    echo '</textarea></form>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have semicolons missing after the echo statements and your php likely has `display_errors` and `display_startup_errors` set to false and/or `error_reporting` disabled, which is why you get a blank page.

You can lint the file from the commandline to check for syntax errors with `php -l [filename]`

Comment: I have changed it to this and still no luck  echo "<textarea name=""textarea"" id=""textarea"" cols=""45"" rows=""5"">[$key:]$value</textarea>";

Comment: @Gerald the line above that is missing one too